# Unable to set focus on and edit a cell in slick grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I am using slick grid. On top of the grid, we have a text box. When user enters a value in textbox and tabs out, we need to enter a new row into the grid.

This is how the code looks:

```
gridOptions = {

            useCheckBoxField: 'selected',
            data: 'data',
            columns: 'columns',
            enableCellNavigation: true,
            enableColumnReorder: true,
            editable: true,
            autoEdit: true,
            multiColumnSort: true,
            rowSelectionModel: 'selectedRows',
            enableAddRow: true
        }
```

This is how the first column looks which I am trying to edit.

```
{id: 'id', name: 'id', field: 'id', editor: Slick.Acsiom.Editors.Text, sortable: true, width: 210, minWidth: 100},
```

This is the code to enter new row and then make the first cell editable and set the focus on the cell.

```
var d =  $scope.$grid.grid.getData();
               $scope.$grid.grid.invalidateRow(d.length);
               //Adds the new row as the first row.
               d.unshift(item);
               $scope.$grid.grid.updateRowCount();
               $scope.$grid.grid.setData(d);
                   $scope.selectedRows = [];
                   $scope.selectedRows = [0];

               //Sets the first row and first column as editable
               $scope.$grid.grid.setActiveCell($scope.selectedRows,0);
               $scope.$grid.grid.gotoCell(0,0,true);
```

**Problem**: Everything works fine, except the cell remains uneditable. User has to manually click on cell to edit it. How can I make the cell editable as soon as a row is added?

Comment: If `.editActiveCell` isn't working, we might need a jsbin/working example of the issue to see what is interfering with making the cell editable.

Comment: The solutions provided by others using `editActiveCell()` should give the desired result. A quick mock-up of them in action can be seen [in this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Au70okKiOWPqNHKEhmcr?p=preview), just click the 'Edit Cell' button.  If this does not work then perhaps the issue is with the code in the custom editor `Slick.Acsiom.Editors.Text`. A plnkr / fiddle replicating the issue is required to determine what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grid.editActiveCell` - see more here https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#wiki-editActiveCell

After setting active cell, make it editable.

```
var grid = $scope.$grid.grid;
var row = $scope.selectedRows[0];
var col = 0;
grid.setActiveCell(row, col);
grid.editActiveCell(Slick.Acsiom.Editors.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. But it does not make cell editable. I still need to click on cell to make it editable.

Comment: is `$scope.selectedRows` a number or and array? You may need `$scope.$grid.grid.setActiveCell($scope.selectedRows[0], 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar problem, I needed the following three lines to open a cell for editing.

```
grid.setActiveCell(row, col);
grid.setOptions({editable: true});
grid.editActiveCell(grid.getCellEditor());
```

If a cell was validated for editing, I used the booleans 'editCell' and 'cellEditOpen', and set grid.setOptions({editable: false}); as necessary

Comment: Thank you for quick help. Even this solution did not worked for me